# For which values of $c_1, c_2$ and $c_3$ is (1, 2, -2) a local minimum

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

Consider the problem

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
\min & x^2 -2xy + 2xz +y^2 + 4yz + z^2 + c_1x + c_2y + c_3z \\ 
s.t & g(x,y,z)=-x^2 -4xy - 4xz -2y^2 -4yz - 2z^2 + x -y+z+4  =0 \\
\; & h(x,y,z)=-x-y+z+5 \geq 0 
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

For which values of $c_1, c_2$ and $c_3$ you can guarantee that p=(1, 2, -2) is a local minimum? Repeat the same question, trying to find the values that you can guarantee it is not a local minimum and you can't decide if it is or not.

**My attempt** I first tried to check the first order necessary condition. Since both the restrictions are active at this point:

$$ \nabla f(p) + \lambda \nabla g(p) + \mu \nabla (-h)(p) = 0$$
for $\mu \geq 0$. Getting the gradients and substituting we have

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
-6+c_1-\lambda+\mu=0\\
-6+c_2-5\lambda+\mu = 0\\
6+c_3-3\lambda-\mu =0
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

From first and third, and second and third we have

$$\lambda = \frac{c_1+c_3}{4} = \frac{c_2+c_3}{8}$$

I've tried to get $\mu$ in function of the c's, but this just help to find when it is not a minimum. Also, I couldnt use it to check the second order conditions.

Maybe what I got is wrong, but I am stuck. I would be glad if someone could help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If (1, 2, -2) satisfies all KKT conditions, then it is a local minimum.

Comment: I know, what I am trying to find are the values of c's such that this points satisfies the kkt conditions

Comment: It seems you showed a necessary condition is that $$\frac{c_1+c_3}{4} = \frac{c_2+c_3}{8}$$

Comment: Hm, yes. We can find some restriction for those values if we substitute and use the fact that we must have $\mu \geq 0$. But I don't see how to verify the second order.

Comment: So your problem becomes to find the solutions to the systems constructed by KKT conditions, which may have infinite number of solutions.

Comment: Yes, but the second order looks really hard to verify for those values of $\lambda$. I am asking my self if I made wrong calculations or if there is a easier way.